# Can Django website be ported as Flutter based mobile app without Django REST APIs?

Tags: django, flutter

We have a Django based website with PostgreSql database. We don't want to develop any REST APIs for the current website. So we would like to know whether it is possible to develop a mobile app using Flutter when our website doesn't have REST APIs?

Best regards

Comment: Read about WebView, but I am not sure if Flutter supports that, and even, why use Flutter for WebView? You could use anything else that is lighter and works faster even on older phones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter just to implement browser features to your app.

But I prefer you NOT to use Flutter for this project. Just use Native Apps if you are not planning to add something in your app that needs cross-platform.

Building Native WebView apps will improve your app's performance more than Flutter.